# Testing sequentially nested models

Tags: self-study, model-selection, multiple-comparisons, likelihood-ratio

Assume I have a simple model with (at least) four parameters $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3, \beta_4$. If I would want to test $H_o: \beta_1 = \beta_2 \& \beta_3 = \beta_4$ by using the likelihood ratio test. And suppose this gives an insignificant result. Now if I were to test $H_o \beta_1 = \beta_2$ using the likelihood ratio test and this approach is significant. I was wondering if there is any reason to prefer the first or second result?